# Installing Ubuntu doesn't recognize my ssd

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop (Dell Vostro 5481) but when I get to where I have to choose the partition it only shows my flash drive but not my ssd where I want to install it. I have raid turned off and it's set to ahci.

Comment: check bios or uefi settings

Comment: Is UEFI the most recent firmware? And if SSD most recent firmware? What version & flavor of Ubuntu? How much RAM? If 4GB, you may want lightweight flavor. to see firmware: `sudo lshw | grep -m 1 -A 5 "*-firmware"` & 
`udisksctl status
` Compare to vendor's support site. Flavors, I like Kubuntu, but that is opinion: https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours

Comment: As far as I can tell they are both up to date, although I couldn't actually find anything for the UEFI firmware on Dell's site. I'm trying to install Ubuntu Desktop 24.04.4 LTS. It has 16gigs of ram so i don't think that would affect it.